Choosing which relevant code blocks to supply as context for VS Code Github Copilot
I am using Github Copilot on VS Code, version 1.95 Oct release.
I have been wondering how one can supply a manually selected context of files and codeblocks to ask in copilot chat.
Basically, I want to get the effect of you copying codeblock A from file A, codeblock B from file B, codeblock C from file C, then pasting them in the copilot chatbox, and proceeding to ask your questions. The response will be very focused on those codeblocks you have supplied. However, this process is very tedious and is dynamic. You do not want paste these blocks to the chat every time, and even if we only extract codeblocks, when combined it can get pretty large taking up a good portion of your chatbox.
If you use the selection feature, it only uses the active editor tab's currently selected codeblock, which does not work if you want to include other selected codeblocks in other file tabs.
Attempts I tried:

In normal chat, you can drag files into the copilot chatbox, or click the "attach context" clip icon to choose which files to use as context. But it has some downsides:

You cannot choose which codeblock to use within each file. If a file is very large, a lot of irrelevant information is supplied
Once you send a chat message, the previously chosen files as context are removed, making you either have to reselect the files, or hope the past history summarization ability of the LLM somehow captures what you want to ask. It would be great if there is an option to save the chosen files


There is a new feature in v1.95 which is copilot edits, it allows you to select files I want into a Working Set, which acts as the context supplied in normal chat. However,

It directly modifies your code, while I mostly want it to give me code suggestions that I can review, modify and add accordingly. Here you need to open diff checker and manually choose which parts to revert back and which parts to keep
It still chooses entire files instead of codeblocks


@workspace feature. It looks at your entire codebase, does some of semantic search to look for relevant files based on your question, and use those files and perhaps the relevant codeblocks to act as context, yet,

I do not want it to have to go through looking at my entire codebase. I want to narrow down its search space in a custom manner so it can pinpoint accurately the relevant context
You can put relevant files you want into a separate folder, then open this folder on VS Code making this folder of subset of files the entire @workspace, to act as selecting relevant files you want. But as you edit your code, you have to update both your real codebase and this subset folder, which is inconvenient



In summary, I want to manually select relevant codeblocks in files to supply as context to copilot chat at once.

Understanding your problem, there does not have multi-selection codeblocks on one or multiple files, the reason behind that probably the input of these LLMs are limited, where all inputs should be itself summarized and mapped reduce to a proper small size, subsequently make sure all generations can work smoothly
There is a workaround you can try, create an instruction file, you will input the persist file names, its line of code (or relevant function name) should focus, for every prompt chat it will preload and include the instruction to have better answer.
https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/customizing-copilot/adding-custom-instructions-for-github-copilot
